# Delete a git commit pushed on a remote branch

Tags: git

We use git and GitFlow as versioning tools, and I'm facing a problem that I am quite sure some people have already encountered.

In a feature branch, a colleague did a commit in which a lot of useless files were inserted (all binary and IDE metadata files). This commit was pushed. Now this colleague submits a pull request, and I don't want to integrate all these useless files into `develop`.

**Now, my git repository is quite huge, and a git clone becomes a long and boring process...**

The first (and easy) solution is to remove these files from the feature branch, and commit without these files (or do a `revert commit`). But if I do that, my git repository will remain quite big because objects (files) will not be removed from the history (because git still knows about them!).

What I would like is to "cancel" this commit.

The following picture shows my problem (the topmost commit is the oldest):

[image: Graph of git repository]

**How can I remove this commit and make my git clone quick again ?**

*PS: Thanks to GitGraphJS for their useful tools to draw git graphs!*

Comment: Why not just remove the branch as it's not merged?

Comment: Do an interactive rebase of the branch, fixing the commit in question, then reissue the pull request.

Comment: You can revert the commit?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are several methods to delete or undo the commit. In that case, you can use `git revert` or `git rebase` or `git reset`.

One information, `git rebase` don't add one extra commit compared to using git revert. git revert adds one extra commit during the merge. If you're not familiar with using git rebase, I suggest you use `git revert` then.

**Revert**

```
git revert <commit-ID>
```

after that you commit the changes and push that commit to your origin.

---

**Reset**

You can delete the last pushed commit, after doing this you have to push your branch. You can decide either to merge or rebase the feature branch to development branch.

```
git reset –-hard HEAD~1
```

or

```
git reset HEAD^ --hard
```

---

**Rebase**

This command will lead to interactive section of editor, from there you can pick

```
 git rebase -i HEAD~
```

In the interactive section, it lists all the commits. Delete the one you want to get rid off. Finish the rebase and push force to the repo.

`git rebase --continue` then push your branch.

Answer (score -1):

The below commands will remove the history of commits after a certain commit id, if you reset to that particular commit id

1. (optional) This command will help you check the commit from which it started diverging from the source: `git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --graph`
2. Once you know the commit ID, you can do `git reset --hard <commit_id>`
3. Then you push the changes to Github `git push --force`